# How can I debug an AWS EC2 instance randomly becoming unreachable

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

We have an EC2 instance which becomes unreachable randomly. It has only started recently, and seems to only happen outside of business hours.

We are finding that the instance websites, WHM, SSH, even a terminal ping is all unreachable. However, the instance is running and health checks are fine in AWS console.

We used to have this with another instance but that just randomly stopped doing it at some point.

I have checked the CPU usage and the last 2 weeks, it has hit 100% 4 times but the times when that happened, are not when the instance goes down and I'm not sure they're even related.

The instance has WHM/cPanel installed, has not reached disk usage limit, nor bandwidth usage limit. We have cPHulk Brute Force Protection installed and running so surely can't be brute force attack?

It is resolved by stopping, then starting the instance, but we have clients viewing links and with the server going down outside of business hours and clients in different timezones.

Comment: Can you share the CloudWatch metrics as image? 
Did you check the cpu credit balance?

Comment: @qkhanhpro The credit usage is an average of about 1 I believe, and has between 4 and 6 about once a day (most, but not all days) and in the last 2 weeks there is 1 spike of 9. Sorry for my lack of AWS knowledge, but what do CPU credits do and what is the limit? What CloudWatch metrics graph do you want to see, and how do I post an image as a comment?

Comment: You can try to look at here https://medium.com/enigma-shards/amazon-aws-we-got-caught-out-by-cpu-credits-192607b84ed8

Comment: @qkhanhpro thanks, so I still don't understand what CPU credits are and that article doesn't help me identify my problem. Got any guides on being able to debug what's going on? I didn't setup this instance, nor do I care about AWS enough to learn it, hence why I'm on here asking for help.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you try installing a CloudWatch Agent to the EC2 instance in order to get the metrics and be able to analyze them further.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/Install-CloudWatch-Agent.html

Comment: They're installed and I've been looking at them and the CPU usage, in the last 2 weeks, has hit 100% 4 times but the times, there might be a correlation between that and when the instance goes down, but it's hard to identify as the instance goes down outside of work hours. Also CPU usage reaching 100% doesn't always happen on the same day as the instance going down.